# Rank the frequency in the frequency table

Tags: r

I have a frequency table which consists two columns "Zip.code" and
"frequency", I would like to rank the frequency from the most to the least.

I have tried all the packages here but not worked.

https://dabblingwithdata.wordpress.com/2017/12/20/my-favourite-r-package-for-frequency-tables/

My table looks like this:

```
       Zip.code    Frequency
 1     10408       482
 2     10412       351
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
library(dplyr)

df <-
  tibble(
    zip = c(10408, 10412, 10431),
    freq = c(482, 351, 501)
  )

df %>% 
  arrange(desc(freq)) %>% 
  mutate(rank = row_number())
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in `Base`:

```r
df$Rank <-  rev(rank(df$Frequency))

df
#>   Zip.code Frequency Rank
#> 1    10408       482    1
#> 2    10412       351    2
```

***Data:***

```r
df<- read.table(text="Zip.code Frequency
                      10408       482
                      10412       351",  header=T)
```

Comment: Thanks but this one gave me the rank but the 1st rank was not the most frequent (or have the highest frequency Zip.code). Thanks though

Comment: @Chen Well, it's impossible. Care to share part of your data than I can reproduce the error/mistake you pointing out? Share the output of this instead of copy pasting: `dput(head(data,20))`. Otherwise, my reproducible example shows that this works, and honestly this is much simpler than something I'd have doubts about.